# AJAX JSON Invalid format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vb.net

I'm trying to pass a JSON array through AJAX into a vb.net web function but i'm getting an error.

```
var retDets = {};


for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "hidden") {
        if (inputs[i].value !== "") {
            value.push(inputs[i].value)
            name.push(inputs[i].name)
            retDets[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
        }

//console.log(JSON.stringify(retDets))

args = '{"retDets":"' + JSON.stringify(retDets) + '"}';
aj('payment2', returnFunc, args, failedCallBack);
```

the web function its suppose to be calling is this (just for test purposes)

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function payment2(retDets() As String) As String
    Dim a As String() = retDets
    Dim b As String
    Return b
End Function
```

I'm getting the following error :

`{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"Invalid object passed in, \\u0027:\\u0027 or \\u0027}\\u0027 expected. (15): {\\\"retDets\\\":\\\"{\\\"__VIEWSTATE\\\":\\\"/wEPDwULLTE0MDkxNzYwNDNkZIvZ4V6cac737n6rhojsjcpPY/VJaIhxf+LCGOM/JDUz\\\",\\\"PSPID\\\":\\\"cum1rp\\\",\\\"ORDERID\\\":\\\"1508ORD\\\",\\\"AMOUNT\\\":\\\"25000\\\",\\\"CURRENCY\\\":\\\"GBP\\\",\\\"LANGUAGE\\\":\\\"en_UK\\\",\\\"CN\\\":\\\"Nick\\\",\\\"EMAIL\\\":\\\"nickw@wdm.co.uk\\\",\\\"SHASIGN\\\":\\\"d22df14635f84283f9ba58ded25aa1716773893d\\\",\\\"TITLE\\\":\\\"WDM Payment Gateway\\\",\\\"BGCOLOR\\\":\\\"#4e84c4\\\",\\\"TXTCOLOR\\\":\\\"#FFFFFF\\\",\\\"TBLBGCOLOR\\\":\\\"#FFFFFF\\\",\\\"TBLTXTCOLOR\\\":\\\"#000000\\\",\\\"BUTTONBGCOLOR\\\":\\\"#00467F\\\",\\\"BUTTONTXTCOLOR\\\":\\\"#FFFFFF\\\",\\\"LOGO\\\":\\\"fill here your logo file name\\\",\\\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\\\":\\\"B6E7D48B\\\"}\\\"}\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Scr`

Comment: You seem to have an error in the middle of the JSON - which would seem to account for the problem. Have you attempted to debug the cause of that error?

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
args = '{"retDets":"' + JSON.stringify(retDets) + '"}';
```

The output is going to have nested quotes.

```
{"retDets":"{"asdasd":"asdasdas","ASdasdsad":"khkjhkjhjkh"}"}';
```

Get rid of the quotes

```
args = '{"retDets":' + JSON.stringify(retDets) + '}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I forgot to include that i have also tried this and also got back an error.

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"No parameterless constructor defined for type of \\u0027System.String[]\\u0027.\",\"StackTrace\":\"

Comment: Well than that thing is expecting a string??

Comment: Still no luck - removed the quotes and still receiving an error. before I try and send retDets to the web function its already populated with an array of 20 items.